# WCF Service accepts simple JSON string but rejects JSON set with 400 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, wcf, sqlite

I'm currently working on a PhoneGap app which communicates with our database via a WCF web service.

I have made many requests to the server and retrieved data with no problem but in each case i was only passing in a couple of parameters as a JSON string which I created manually (no stringify). Now I have encountered a problem when trying to read from my local SQLite database and then send the information as JSON to the web service. The service is returning a 400 error with the following:

Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'uploadData'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find an attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'. Found value 'array'.

I am encoding the JSON as follows:

```
database.transaction(function(tx) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE something=something";
    tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, results) {
        var resultSet = new Array();

        for (i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = results.rows.item(i);
            resultSet[i] = row;         
        }

        var json = JSON.stringify(resultSet);
    }
}
```

I then send the JSON string via an ajax request using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://someurl/myService.svc/uploadData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: json,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {/*do something*/}, 
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#test').html(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + " - " + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
```

My web service just keeps throwing back the same error. My question is this...How can I read from the local database and convert the result set into a usable JSON string to be sent via ajax.

Thanks in advance. If more info needed or the problem is unclear please let me know and I'll do my best to provide more information.

**EDIT:** Tried removing the stringify but I'm still getting a 400 error. The error is a little different this time though:

Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'uploadData'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Encountered unexpected character 'u'.

**EDIT:** I've discovered that even a manually created JSON string that is perfectly valid still causes the error. It doesn't happen when sending a couple of parameters such as:

```
{"name" : "dean", "age" : 23}
```

It works perfectly fine. It's only rejecting sets of results such as:

```
[{"name" : "dean", "age" : 23},{"name" : "bob", "age" : 25}]
```

The method is defined in WCF interface as follows:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

 string uploadData(string data);
```

It seems it's more of a problem with the WCF service than the JSON string itself.
Does anyone know why WCF would accept a simple JSON string but reject a set? This is a major problem which has completely halted the development of the project so any help is greatly appreciated!

**SOLVED:**  Instead of passing the encoded JSON string directly I instead sent is as a value of another JSON string with key "data". So, as above I have my SQLite results as:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(resultSet);
```

I then pass it to the WCF service as follows:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({ data : json }),
...
```

And it now works fine.

Answer (score -1):

The `JSON.stringify` step is unnecessary because jQuery's AJAX engine does that automatically. Just pass in the result set array as the `data` property in the request options:

```
...
data: resultSet,
...
```

What you're doing now is stringifying an array to JSON, then asking jQuery to-restringify that resulting string as JSON before sending it to the server.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that explains a few things. I'm home now but I'll try it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: Tried you solution but still getting the 400 error. Updated OP with details